# PHP: create row and colum class in li

Tags: php

there are 20 li

```
  <ul>
      <li id="1"></li>
      <li id="2"></li>
      <li id="3"></li> <!--- Row1--->

      <li id="4"></li>
      <li id="5"></li>
      <li id="6"></li><!--- Row2--->

      <li id="7"></li>
      <li id="8"></li>
      <li id="9"></li><!--- Row3--->

      <li id="10"></li> 
      <li id="11"></li>
      <li id="12"></li><!--- Row4--->
  </ul>
```

i want to give class to first 3 li element 1,2,3  to row 1

```
 li 4,5,6 to row 2
```

is it possible with li??

```
 <?php $i=0;?>

<ul>
  <?php foreach($data as $da):?>
     <li id="<?php echo $i+1;?>"></li>
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code that generates this list?

Comment: Why not use tables instead?

Comment: i can not use table because li contains product data.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.row { float:left; }
.row > ul { display:inline-block; }
</style>
<ul>
  <?php

  $i=0;
  foreach($data as $da){    
     if($i%3===0){
          echo ($i!==0 ? '</ul>' : null );
          echo "<li class='row'><ul><li id='".($i+1)."'></li>";
     }else{
          echo "<li id='".($i+1)."'></li>";
     }
     $i++;
  }
  ?>
</ul>
```

You may also need to introduce the clearfix class.

Answer (score 0):

There are no 'Rows' as such in a Unordered List.

You can certainly apply classes to the elements based on the sequence and could have a 'rowEnd' or 'rowStart' class applied to the last or first list item in that row without much hassle, but what are you trying to acheive by grouping them in rows?

A table sounds like a more natural fit to this type of data perhaps?

Amended Answer:

```
<?php

    $data = array();
    $data = array_pad($data, 50, 'x'); // Just creating some dummy data..

?>
<?php $i=0;
    $row = 1; // First row as default...

?>

<ul>
  <?php foreach($data as $da):?>
    <?php
        if(($i > 2 && $i % 3 == '0')) { // Increment where $i is divisble by 3
            $row++;
        }
    ?>
     <li class="row<?=$row?>" id="<?php echo $i+1;?>"><?=$da?></li>
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah i can add firstrow and last row class that i know.. what i am looking for is i want to apply row1 class to first3 li , row2 to second 3 li and so on.. there i can do that by simply adding the code nkmol suggested but to get complete dynamic as li will increase the loop will automatically add row class to li  which is quite complex.

Comment: See revised answer... should be what you need I think...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but i understand `i want to give class to first 3 li element`.

So why not check your iteration if it's lower as 3 ?(iteration 0, 1 , 2)

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($data as $da):?>
        <?php if($i < 3) :?>
            <li class="yourClass" id="<?php echo $i+1;?>">Got class</li>
        <?php else :?>
            <li id="<?php echo $i+1;?>">No class</li>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If you want to have from every 'row' the first 3 li's. Well there no rows in an unorded list. You can just genereate tables for this or you can create multiple `<ul>`s that will stand for an 'row'.

Comment: thanks for help but using above code if there will be 50 products then  i have to add mathematicall opetion all the time for example     if($minus < 3 ||$minus == 3){ echo 'row1';}elseif($minus > 3 || $minus < 6){echo 'row2';}elseif($minus >6 || $minus < 9){echo 'row3';} else{}  is ther dynamic solution that will continously apply the row class likr first 3 row1 second 3 row2 third 3 row3 so on..

Comment: Well if you have one row. Yes then you have to do it manually. Add another loop which defines how much row's you will have. NOTE that by a row i mean a `<ul>` element! Inside another loop of how much items per row and then my validation. That would work. --You have no rows--

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you close your ul, and then bring another ul. Then float left your ul's with a right spacing.

```
<?php $i=0;?>
<?php $x=0;?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach($data as $da):?>
     <li id="<?=$i+1;?>"></li>
     <?php if ($x == 2) {
      echo "</ul><ul>";
      $x = 0;     
     ?>
  <?php $i++; $x++ ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```